# Industrial RF replacement for Xbee based UART communication

Tags: rf, wireless, can, industrial

I have used Xbee's several times and I am working on a basic project which involves multiple MCUs talking to a central MCU and sending some updates such as Temp, GPS and etc...

Very basic setting bunch of Atmels ATMega controllers and they each have an Xbee connected to them. I am trying to take this a step forward and like to have professional design and printed on a PCB, also I have had several orders for the network, so I like to take this from an XBee based system to something more robust. I have looked into some TI's RF transceivers and Atmel's as well, but since I have never done an communication project from scratch I am scared to step into this dark area. I know RF is nothing but pain, dealing with the antenna's and noise, and etc... 
I was wondering if anyone can help me with some design notes, and examples, maybe a chip that can be interfaced and would be easy to program. again this is a really basic 2-way network and I don't need a long range. It's a residential building solution so I am thinking about 2.4Ghz, or 900 Mhz would do just fine, all I care is to bring down the cost of production while keeping the design and implementation process fairly easy.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're designing for higher quantity or commercial release, you will be facing one big problem for rolling your own RF solution: compliance. Even though most electrical and electronic regulations are voluntary or self-certification, anything RF quickly needs to be FCC approved to be sold at all (assuming you're a US person). This is why it's actually a good idea to stick with a ready-made module. This way you can rely on the certification and compliance testing that they have already done.

Of course, this still means a lot of vendors remain. But I would definitely recommend sticking with complete modules instead of trying to build your own. They are slightly more expensive in quantity than for instance an nRF24L01+ solution (currently the lowest-cost fairly robust low-data rate RF solution on the market), but you don't have to go through expensive audits and tests.

Comment: Thanks. Fair enough, but the problem is not just the cost. Xbee is a hobby based module. It doesn't look that robust, and professional, also having it attached to a breakout board, makes it difficult to integrate it to a SMT circuit and wastes lots of space. I have PCBed my circuit and now I have to have a Through Hole only because of Xbee. Any suggestion that I can use a device similar to Xbee but in 'pre-fab' category? Have you used ZigBit?

Comment: Well, that is just a matter of image and marketing then. If you don't like the XBee because you feel it's a hobby module, then you should choose something that feels more professional - although this really gets into the 'I don't like green PCBs' territory. And you can get lots of variants of XBee including SMT modules like this one: http://www.digiwireless-solutions.com/Bizit/store/img/p/209-258-thickbox.jpg .

Comment: WOW, taht's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks man, problem solved!

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of modules based on NRF24 or look/work alikes. Often they are available either with pins or as 'SMD module'. I sell the HopeRF RFM73 in pin version, but they also have an 'SMD' version, which is just the PCB without the pins:

[image]